# web service - PHP - Iniciante

Tags: php

Estou começando a estudar *PHP* e preciso de uma ajuda. Preciso consumir um *web service*, porem não estou conseguindo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Tenho wsdl:= 
http://200.171.223.154:98/wstelegram/wstelegram.apw?wsdl que pede a seguinte estrutura:

Requisição SOAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <PEDIDO>STRING</PEDIDO>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Resposta da Requisição SOAP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
   <CRET>STRING</CRET>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Já tentei diversos modelos na net e não estou acertando, fico muito agradecido pela ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Instancia o objeto `$soap = new SoapClient('http://200.171.223.154:98/wstelegram/wstelegram.apw?wsdl');` e depois utilize `var_dump( $soap->RETTELEGRAM(['PEDIDO' => 'PEDIDO-AQUI']) );`

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://200.171.223.154:98/wstelegram/wstelegram.apw?wsdl');

$function = 'RETTELEGRAM';

$arguments= array('RETTELEGRAM'=>array(
    'PEDIDO' => 'w'
));

$options = array('location' => 'http://200.171.223.154:98/wstelegram/wstelegram.apw');


$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

echo 'Response: ';

return($result->RETTELEGRAMRESULT);
```